# Ошибка разбора : синтаксическая ошибка, неожиданное 'while' (T_WHILE)

Tags: php

Вот такая вот ошибка
Ошибка разбора : синтаксическая ошибка, неожиданное 'while' (T_WHILE)

//[image: введите сюда описание изображения] введите сюда код

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users img_file WHERE id='$id' ");

    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $result=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `textArea` WHERE id='$id'"); // запрос на выборку
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    function get_text($id) {
      $singles = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
      foreach ($singles as $single) {
        return $single;
      }
    }

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      if(!empty($row['textArea']))
      echo  '<div class="media mb-4 p-4 status-content">' .

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($sql)) {           
        if (!$row['img_file']) {
          echo '<img class="mr-5 avatar" src="https://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/instance/bs4/assets/images/profile.jpg"/>';
        } else {
          echo "<img class='mr-5 avatar' style='width:300px; border-radius: 100%;height: 300px;' src='" . $row['img_file'] . "' alt='' />";
        }              
      }


    '<div class="media-body">' .
    '<h4 class="text-author text-warning">' . $row['login'] . '</h4>' .

    '<p class="text-white">' . $row['textArea'] . '</p>' .

              '</div>'.
            '</div>';
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: если у вас что-то неожиданное, то смотрите что перед этим написано. у вас там конкатенация строки.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: да это тот же самый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1062462 думаю пользователь просто создал новый аккаунт чтобы уж точно помогли.

Answer (score 0):

Замените здесь

```
echo  '<div class="media mb-4 p-4 status-content">' .
```

точку на ;

```
echo  '<div class="media mb-4 p-4 status-content">';
```